# How to check if email already exists in Real Time Database of Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android

[structure of my realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFSKi.png%27)

The root node is named users and its children are set with usernames.
I want to check if an email already exists. I am trying something like:

```
 private boolean validateEmail(){
        email = inp_email.getEditText().getText().toString();

        ArrayList<String> list_of_emails = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot user: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    list_of_emails.add(user.child("email").getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        if (list_of_emails.contains(email)){
            inp_email.setError("Email already exists!");
            return false;
        }
 if(email.isEmpty()){
            inp_email.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!email.contains("@gmail.com")) {
            inp_email.setError("Invalid Email");
            return false;
        }else {
            inp_email.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
}
```

I tried using add event listeners and tried setting a boolean value on which if email exists must turn to true, but that doesn't work and I don't know what are other ways to do it. thing is i want a boolean return value!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing might be related to the asynchronous nature of Firebase database operations. The `ValueEventListener` runs asynchronously, so when you check for `list_of_emails.contains(email)` immediately after setting up the listener, the data might not have been fetched yet.

To solve this problem, you can move the validation logic inside the onDataChange method or use a callback to handle the asynchronous nature of Firebase. I'll provide you with an example using a callback:

```
private interface EmailValidationCallback {
    void onResult(boolean isEmailValid);
}

private void validateEmail(final EmailValidationCallback callback) {
    email = inp_email.getEditText().getText().toString();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> list_of_emails = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot user : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                list_of_emails.add(user.child("email").getValue().toString());
            }

            boolean isEmailValid = !list_of_emails.contains(email) && !email.isEmpty() && email.contains("@gmail.com");
            callback.onResult(isEmailValid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            callback.onResult(false);
        }
    });
}

// Example usage
private void yourValidationMethod() {
    validateEmail(new EmailValidationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(boolean isEmailValid) {
            if (!isEmailValid) {
                inp_email.setError("Email already exists or is invalid!");
            } else {
                inp_email.setError(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This way, the validateEmail method takes a callback as a parameter, and the validation result is handled inside the onResult method of the callback. This ensures that the validation happens after the data is fetched from the Firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

**email** user enter email and we get and put inside this object

```
                databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.child("email").hasChild(email)){
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "email is Already registed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        else {
                      // do here what you want 
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: can you look at my updated question and understand what i actually want? @Hanif Shaikh